# Bike ID - please help!

Tags: identify-this-bike

Just getting back into biking after about a decade and looking to possibly purchase a new one. I saw a pic of this in GQ and looks beautiful, simple, and city oriented. Can anyone tell what it might be? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: You might get a better response asking the magazine, the article's author, or the photographer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see is a US power plug, suggesting its US based.  Thickslicks are very much a "cafe-hipster-singlespeed" tyre and rarely seen on transport bikes or fast bikes so this looks like a one-speed bike with a front brake (wise plan)

There are toe clips on the flat pedals, implying that this is a fixed gear not a singlespeed.
  **I'd not recommend fixed gear for your situation.**

It has 700c aluminium wheels with either a steel or possibly an aluminium frame.  The thin tubes imply steel but its hard to tell from one small photo.  I doubt there is any carbon fibre on that bike.

The bars are called "bullhorns" and are "trendy-urban"  The "horns" risk catching anything you might brush past, so are more for looks than function.

As for colour, I see white tyres, white saddle, and white bartape.  This bike has never been ridden in its entire life and looks brand new.   White simply does not stay white on a bike for long, with tyres turning grey quickly, followed by bartape.

You could walk into almost any bike shop and find a commuter/hybrid/flatbar bike of similar shape.  Then get a leg over and see how you feel.  Do also try out other shapes of bike too - remember GQ is not a cycling magazine, its an interior decoration showpiece, and that bike as pictures is merely window dressing.

**It is not a "working bike", it is a show pony.**

Comment: If you actually look at the picture, you'll see quite a few stains on the tires, saddle and handlebars.

Comment: @ojs fair - the tyres do look slightly dirty when zoomed in.  Which reminds me that photo-retouching is also a thing in the publications industry, so there's a chance things have been painted out too.

Comment: This was  bought in Austin, Texas according to the GQ article, and a quick search of Austin bikeshops shows single speeds with thickslicks. The rear bike wheel has brake marks showing it has been swapped with the front, meaning this thing is getting used and serviced.

Answer (score 0):

It might be this? Or something similar?